# Choices in choice field does not get created - PnP-Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-column, choice-field, pnp

I'm trying to create a choice field / site column with choices. The field got created but no fields are available. It's basically a empty choice field.

```
Add-SPOFieldFromXml -FieldXml '<Field DisplayName="Dokument type" Type="Choice" Name="Dokument_Type" StaticName="Dokument_Type" ID="{b7da4426-ec4b-474d-9322-3b0638fb482b}" Group="Company" Required="FALSE"><Choices><Choice>choice1</Choice><Choice>choice2</Choice></Choices></Field>'
```

Comment: Can you make your edit an answer and mark it as such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug, but you can use:

```
Add-SPOField -InternalName "DD" -DisplayName "dd" -Group "D" -Type Choice -Choices @("111","222")
```

https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/issues/255

Comment: Hello @Plexus81, you wrote Powershell script (if i'm correct). but i'm provisionning my Site Columns using PnP. SO i have an XML Template for my columns. Could you help me finding your solution in .XML please?
My XML structure is the same as yours.